# Adding callback for drag and drop event for ng-nestable data-binding issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using [Ng-nestable](https://github.com/kamilkp/ng-nestable) and it does not have any callback event for when the element is dragged and dropped, i started by creating those. but the data model doesn't reflect the changes:

Plunker [HERE](http://embed.plnkr.co/UoDGJ12VlMhgj27X7oZs/preview)

Here you can see 2 lists list1/list2 in nested tree format with their data serialised and displayed below.

Try to drag element 12 from list2 and drop it in list 1 between 2 and 3

Thus the parent 1 will now have 3 children, which are represented in the serialized format correctly. However, if you see the console, where I have tried to print the node value 1, it still shows the children as 2.

Looks like delay in ng-model update, but I don't know how to resolve this.

Can you pls help ..